# Trying to mock two classes with Groovy Spock Mock: GroovyCastException

Tags: groovy, spock

I try to mock two classes in a Jenkins Pipeline var-script, but however I order the definition of the Mock I receive a GroovyCastException, while the mock for the second class is initiated

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Mock for type 'ClassA'' with class 'com.pipeline.ClassA$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9b005c28' to class 'com.pipeline.DBReader'
```

This is how my Spock-Test looks like:

```
import com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification
import com.pipeline.ClassA
import com.pipeline.DBReader
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException
import hudson.model.Result

class execScriptSpec extends JenkinsPipelineSpecification {
    def execPipelineScript = null

    def mockStage = [timeout: [time: 'mocktime']]
    def mockScript = [...]

def setup() {
    execPipelineScript = loadPipelineScriptForTest("vars/execScript.groovy")
}

def "Test Pipeline-Script"() {

    setup:

      GroovyMock(ClassA, global: true)
      new ClassA(*_) >> Mock(ClassA) {
        loadScope(_) >> null
        loadJsonFromURL(_) >> null
      }

      GroovyMock(DBReader, global: true)
      new DBReader(*_) >> Mock(DBReader) {
        loadDBDriver(_) >> null
      }
  when:
      execPipelineScript(mockScript, mockStage)
  then:
      true
```

And that is the code under test:

```
import com.pipeline.DBReader
import com.pipeline.ClassA

def call(script, stage) {
  def pipelineConfig = script.pipelineConfig
  def stageStatus = pipelineConfig.general.stageStatus

  def projectName = script.env.project

  // DB connection parameters
  def dbName = script.deliveryConfig.system.dbName
  def dbSchema = script.deliveryConfig.system.dbSchema
  def dbServer = script.deliveryConfig.system.dbServer
  def dbUser = script.deliveryConfig.system.dbUser
  // DB Driver to use
  def dbDriver = script.deliveryConfig.system.dbDriver
  def dbPassword = script.env.password

  // Create new DB-Client
  DBReader dbClient = new DBReader(dbName, dbSchema, dbServer, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
  dbClient.loadDBDriver()
   
  def contextParameter = script.params['Context']

  ClassA mapGavToVersionRange = new ClassA(projectName, contextParameter, script)
  classAInstance.loadDeliveryScope( dbClient )
  def url = 'https://some.valid.url'
  classAInstance.loadJsonFromURL(url)

  ...
```

So don't get me wrong: The actual mocking of one or the other class works (if I put only one of them in my test), but as soon as I put both of them, the second one will not work. And I currently have no idea, why this happens.
Would be great, if anybody has an idea :-)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you just make `ClassA` and `DBReader` injectable instead of creating them inside your `call(..)` method? That way your code would become more testable and you wouldn't need hacky solutions like Groovy mocks. If you don't like to inject them via method parameter, extract instance creation into two helper methods which you can easily stub. Decouple your dependencies, that is a basic design principle, also if it is "only" a little script. Having to use Groovy mocks in a situation as simple as this one is a code smell IMO.